# Nested for loop that prints out the numbers backwards?

Tags: java, for-loop

I've got to used a nested for loop to print out the sequence:

```
544333222211111
```

I've written out a nested for loop below but it's printing: `555443321`

```
int i,j;

for(i=5;i>=1;i=i-1)
{
    for(j=1;j<i+1;j+=2)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me how to modify the code above so that it prints `544333222211111` instead?

Comment: you need to make an attempt and tell us where you went wrong before we can help, otherwise we are just doing the work for you

Comment: Try `j++` instead of `j+=2`

Comment: why downvote? he tried, he did not get it. ok, he is new to programming, but downvoting for being inexperienced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
for(j=1;j<i+1;j+=2)
```

try

```
for (j = i; j <= 5; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,j, k = 1;

for(i=5; i>=1; i--)
{
    for(j=1; j<=k; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    k++;
}
```